# Write File Using another group in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have an user id ops which comes under multiple groups like sysgroup,usergroup. When I write to some other user directory by default it is writing under sysgroup. But for some user I need to write with usergroup permission. How can I acheive this?

Here is my sample code

```
if ls n18_????_??????????.txt &> /dev/null; then
     cp n18_????_??????????.txt /export/home/user
     chgrp usergroup /export/home/user/n18_????_??????????.txt
     mv n18_????_??????????.txt $archDir
fi
```

I am copying then changing the group, So each time it changes the group for all the files matching the pattern.

Comment: would setting the `setgid` bit on the folder be sufficient?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas I tried but, when I place files again, that file is getting another group than the folder group.

Comment: The `/export/home/user` directory has the group `usergroup` with `g+s` and the user executing the script also has the group `usergroup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`install`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?install) command allows you to copy a file while specifying the destination file's ownership and permissions.

Incidentally, you might want to avoid [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), although I'm not sure what would be the most idiomatic solution. Simply ignoring any error messages is often a bad idea, but maybe it's the simplest here. (That means you won't be notified e.g. if you lack permissions, though!)

```
 install --group usergroup n18_????_??????????.txt /export/home/user 2>/dev/null &&
 mv n18_????_??????????.txt "$archDir"
```

Note that there is a race condition here.  If new files matching the wildcard could appear while `install` is executing, the `mv` will move away them even though they were not copied.  If you can use Bash-only constructs, try this:

```
list=( n18_????_??????????.txt )  # Expands the wildcard only once
if [ -e "${list[0]}" ]; then
    install --group usergroup "${list[@]}" /export/home/user &&
    mv "${list[@]}" "$archDir"
fi
```

This is altogether a better solution because it will show any warnings or error messages, while running quietly in the normal case.

Answer (score 4):

#### sg

Another way is to use `sg`:

```
sg usergroup bash
```

It summons another shell in which the active group is `usergroup`. It gets back to the original if you exit.

#### usermod

You can also use `usermod` to change the primary group of the user. It makes it the default in every login.

```
usermod -g usergroup user
```

See [sg](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sg) and [usermod](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod).

#### sudo

Yet another way is to use `sudo`. See this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162390/run-as-group-fails-sudo-g) too.

```
sudo -g usergroup id -gn  ## Verify that it works.
sudo -g usergroup bash
```

#### Solution for scripts

You can make the script call itself again with `sudo`.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == __GROUP_CHANGED__ ]]; then
    shift
else
    exec /usr/bin/sudo -g users "$0" __GROUP_CHANGED__ "$@"
fi
```

Or

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = __GROUP_CHANGED__ ]; then
    shift
else
    exec /usr/bin/sudo -g users "$0" __GROUP_CHANGED__ "$@"
fi
```

The concept may also work with `sg` but `sg` does not accept raw arguments for the command. It only accepts a single string argument and pass it to `/bin/sh`. It's not a good method to use when you're passing multiple arguments especially those with spaces to the script. And quoting is a big no.

Comment: I am using this inside shell script. So when I change the script quit.

Comment: I am using this inside shell script. So when I change the group the script quits.

Comment: @Rajesh Consider changing your script's header and run it directly like `./script.sh`. See my update.

Comment: I removed it as it won't work the way it should since shebangs can only accept 2 arguments. I'll just think of another sorry.

Comment: On the shebang remark, you can create a script that does `sg usergroup bash` and point to that as the shebang

Answer (score 2):

First do:

```
newgrp wheel
```

then:

```
touch newfile
```

the file be in the wheel group. From the `newgrp` man-page:

> > The newgrp command is used to change the current group ID during a login session....

and you can also change the group of a file:

```
chown :usergroup oldfile
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am copying the files via script. So when I do newgrp newgroupname in the script the script comes out. Also I am using patterns to copy like cp ???.?? /usr/path. So if I copy and do the chown or chgrp for the patterns all times it will perform for all files in the user directory. Right? Comments please.

Comment: what do you mean "the script comes out"?

Comment: I am trying to do this inside my script as mentioned in my question. So after adding the line newgrp newgroup in the script, while I excute my script after that line the script breaks and exit. Not executing further lines.